# how to get DOM element with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some element like :

```
<button ng-click="weirdFunction()">Pretty Button</button>
```

And function in controller :

```
$scope.weirdFunction = function(element) {
 console.log(element);
}
```

in console log I want to receive this DOM element. I tried to do this in several ways:

1. `<button ng-click="weirdFunction()" ng-model="button">Pretty Button</button>`

   `$scope.weirdFunction = function() {
    console.log($scope.button);
   }`
2. `<button ng-click="weirdFunction(button)" ng-model="button">Pretty Button</button>`
   `$scope.weirdFunction = function(elem) {
    console.log(elem);
   }`
3. `<button ng-click="weirdFunction($element)">Pretty Button</button>`
   `$scope.weirdFunction = function(elem) {
    console.log(elem);
   }`
   But all attempts were failures. Where I'm wrong? How to get an element which clicked?

Comment: use directives if you want to access element , or pass $event inside function

Comment: You could do `ng-click="weirdFunction($event.target)"`, first place why you need DOM there?

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar I want to make some kind of dropup modal window, so button is ElementSibling and when I press on that button function will make `previousElementSibling.style.display = 'inline-block'`

Comment: Can't you think of using ng-class or ng-style to achieve the same?

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar yeah ng-class cool, but I have at least 7 buttons whit their modal windows, and when I press the button it should know that needed to show not all modals, but ElementSibling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try following snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.weirdFunction = function(element) {
     console.log(element);
    }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<button ng-click="weirdFunction($event.currentTarget)">Pretty Button</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Pass $event object to weirdFunction. $event.target gives the element on which the click was triggered.

```
<button ng-click="weirdFunction($event)">Pretty Button</button>
```

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this question now and concludes by creating this function

```
getElement($event){
    return $event.target || $event.srcElement || $event.toElement || $event.path[0];
};
```

At CanIUse it works everywhere.