# Angular access DOM sibling element to alter css class

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

How do I gain access to the respective sibling element of my button from the ngFor iteration on my collection?

Dom Element, I'm attempting to access this DOM element, so I can alter the sibling element div.popup class. As shown in the Codepen example linked at the bottom of the post.

I'm very new with angular, please advise.

```
      <button
        #popBtn
        href="#"
        id="info"
        class="info popup-trigger"
        title="info"
        (click)="PopUp($event)"
      >
        Popup
      </button>
```

Prior to the posting here, I read on the following articles but I couldn't understand completely or relate to it.

[Pass a reference to DOM object with ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240411/pass-a-reference-to-dom-object-with-ng-click)

[how to get DOM element with ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914643/how-to-get-dom-element-with-ng-click)

[How to get the element html clicked in a ngFor to add a css class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609306/how-to-get-the-element-html-clicked-in-a-ngfor-to-add-a-css-class/52609432)

#### Overview of code

Component.html

```
<section class="ArticlesGrid">
  <div *ngFor="let article of articles" class="windowsBox">
    <article class="ui-titlebar">
      <h4 class="ui-titletext">{{article.title}}</h4>
    </article>
    <div class="windowsScreen">
      <button
        #popBtn
        href="#"
        id="info"
        class="info popup-trigger"
        title="info"
        (click)="PopUp($event)"
      >
        Popup
      </button>

      <div class="popup" role="alert">
        <div class="popup-container">
          <a href="#" class="popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
          <p>{{article.content}}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="windowsTech">
      Technologies:
      <span class="THtml"></span>
      <span class="TCss"></span>
      <span class="TJs"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Component.ts

```
  PopUp(event: Event) {
    //console.log(this.viewBtn.nativeElement.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("is-visible"));
    console.log(event);
    // this.viewBtn.nativeElement.
  }
```

SandBox Mockup

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-collection-popup?file=src/app/app.component.html

Function to mirror

https://codepen.io/Gugiui/pen/vweXYR

Thanks for reading my question. I hope you can advise/guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add template reference variable on popup div -

```
<div class="popup" role="alert" #popupDiv>
```

pass it in button click function -

```
(click)="PopUp($event, popupDiv)"
```

change class in PopUp method using plain javascript -

```
PopUp(event: Event, element) {

    element.classList.remove('popup');
    element.classList.add('test');
    console.log(element.classList);
  }
```